# Searching for substring in middle

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with the Firebase Realtime Database, and my "description" subkey is indexed (the below structure has it mentioned).

```
{
    "check123": {
        "description": "Linked In Page",
        "tags": [
            "one"
        ],
        "url": "https://linkedin.com"
    },
    "fb": {
        "description": "My Facebook page",
        "tags": [
            "one",
            "two"
        ],
        "url": "https://facebook.com"
    },
    "twitter": {
        "description": "My Twitter page",
        "url": "https://twitter.com"
    } 
}
```

I wanted to search for "Facebook" in "description" key so that it returns the "fb" key's object. I am able to get it using search term "My Facebook" with below code:

```
get(
      query(
        ref(db, "/dbSubPathToMentionedObject"),
        orderByChild("description"),
        startAt(searchTerm),
        endAt(searchTerm+"\uf8ff")
      )
    )
```

where searchTerm is the variable for the current search term. But I want to search for substring from the middle. Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to search for substring from the middle. Is it possible?

No, it's not. There is no way you can perform a query in the Realtime Database that can return elements containing a particular substring. The best you can do is use the query at the end of your question.

A possible solution, that works for extremely small data sets would be to download all the content in a node and perform the search on the client.

Since the Realtime Database doesn't provide a solution for full-text search, then you should consider using third-party libraries like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search/search-applications), [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/), or [Typesense](https://typesense.org/).

If you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then I recommend you reading the following resource:

- [How to filter Firestore data cheaper?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444)